# What is the difference between "Resource Quota" and "Applied Cluster Resource Quota"

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

There are two ResourceQuotas in my Openshift cluster,
One of them is of type ResourceQuota (RQ) and one other is of type AppliedClusterResourceQuota (ACRQ) as described in their yaml description:

```yaml
kind: AppliedClusterResourceQuota
apiVersion: quota.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
spec:
...
```

```yaml
kind: ResourceQuota
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
spec:
...
```

I'm wondering what is AppliedClusterResourceQuota and what is its difference with ResourceQuota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They control things at different levels.

**ResourceQuota**: this controls the maximum amount of resources such as: CPU and memory, and the maximum number of objects such as services that can be created within a project.

**AppliedClusterResourceQuota**: this controls cluster-wide settings such as resource constraints. It is applicable to all projects and aims to control things at the cluster level (e.g. sum of resource usage).